# Ruby - display PDF file which is not public as part of a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I'm trying to display a pdf file which is stored on the server as part of a view (not just over the whole page, that's why I cannot just use send_file or send_data).

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="' + file_path + '" id="pdf_content">
```

but the file is not public, therefore the browser does not have access to it and will not display it. Any idea how to display the file?

I could, for example, convert it to a base64 image, send it to the view and display it on a canvas but that would be slow and the image will be of lower quality.

Answer (score 0):

the 'file_path' just needs to point to an action in controller which returns the file, such as

```
def return_file
  send_file(path, name, type)
end
```

html:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="/return_file" id="pdf_content">
```